# Problems while building NS-3 with WSL Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, linux, gcc, build, ns-3

I'm trying to install ns-3 on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.2. I'm going to use it for Aqua-Sim which recommends ns-3.26 version for compatibility, which is what I'm trying to install. I got through downloading all the prerequisites and downloads, but am unable to build it; with bake, git or tarballs.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I've checked all the packages, went through the documentation and installed all the prerequisites which exactly matched my version and still nothing. Looking through the error message I think something might be wrong with waf but I'm not sure.

The following are the code/error messages:

## Bake:

```
<user>@LAPTOP-<xxxxxxxx>:/home/bake/bake$ sudo python3 bake.py deploy
Downloading, building and installing the selected modules and dependencies.
Please, be patient, this may take a while!

 >> Downloading ns-3.26 - (Nothing to do, source directory already exists) - OK
 >> Building ns-3.26 - Problem
 > Error:  Critical dependency, module "ns-3.26" failed
   For more information call Bake with --debug and/or -v, -vvv, for full verbose mode (bake --help)
```

Using -vvv doesn't tell why either, exact same message for the error.

## Tarball and Git:

(WIth Git basically the same but had
`util.CommandError: Command ['/usr/bin/python3', 'ns3', 'configure'] exited with code 2`
at the end)

```
<user>@LAPTOP-<xxxxxxxx>:/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26$ sudo ./build.py
# Build NS-3
Entering directory `/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/./ns-3.26'
 =>  /usr/bin/python waf configure --with-pybindgen ../pybindgen-0.17.0.post57+nga6376f2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Node.py", line 312, in ant_iter
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Scripting.py", line 110, in waf_entry_point
    run_commands()
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Scripting.py", line 167, in run_commands
    parse_options()
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Scripting.py", line 140, in parse_options
    Context.create_context('options').execute()
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Options.py", line 146, in execute
    super(OptionsContext,self).execute()
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Context.py", line 93, in execute
    self.recurse([os.path.dirname(g_module.root_path)])
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Context.py", line 134, in recurse
    user_function(self)
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/wscript", line 144, in options
    opt.load('compiler_c')
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Context.py", line 90, in load
    fun(self)
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Tools/compiler_c.py", line 36, in options
    opt.load_special_tools('c_*.py',ban=['c_dumbpreproc.py'])
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Context.py", line 321, in load_special_tools
    lst=self.root.find_node(waf_dir).find_node('waflib/extras').ant_glob(var)
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Node.py", line 361, in ant_glob
    ret=[x for x in self.ant_iter(accept=accept,pats=[to_pat(incl),to_pat(excl)],maxdepth=kw.get('maxdepth',25),dir=dir,src=src,remove=kw.get('remove',True))]
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/.waf3-1.8.19-b1fc8f7baef51bd2db4c2971909a568d/waflib/Node.py", line 361, in <listcomp>
    ret=[x for x in self.ant_iter(accept=accept,pats=[to_pat(incl),to_pat(excl)],maxdepth=kw.get('maxdepth',25),dir=dir,src=src,remove=kw.get('remove',True))]
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/./build.py", line 171, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/./build.py", line 162, in main
    build_ns3(config, build_examples, build_tests, args, build_options)
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/./build.py", line 81, in build_ns3
    run_command(cmd) # waf configure ...
  File "/home/plswork/repos/dude/tarballs26/ns-allinone-3.26/util.py", line 25, in run_command
    raise CommandError("Command %r exited with code %i" % (argv, retval))
util.CommandError: Command ['/usr/bin/python', 'waf', 'configure', '--with-pybindgen', '../pybindgen-0.17.0.post57+nga6376f2'] exited with code 2
```

PS: Removed some of the error message text since it was being marked as spam

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5t350Neb
This is the original question with full error text.